# How can Bob validate Alice’s certiﬁcate?

Tags: certificates

Suppose that Alice has a certiﬁcate `CA1 << Alice >>` issued by the certiﬁcation authority `CA1`, and Bob has a certiﬁcate `CA2 << Bob >>` issued by a diﬀerent certiﬁcation authority `CA2`.

It is known that `CA1` possesses a certiﬁcate `CA2 << CA1 >>` issued by `CA2`. How can Bob validate Alice’s certiﬁcate `CA1 << Alice >>`?

I think CA2 is the root authority but I’m not sure how to proceed with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

As `CA2 << CA1 >>` is a certificate it seems that `CA2` is indeed a root certificate. This is not strictly necessary; `CA2` just needs to be trusted by Bob.  `CA2 << CA1 >>` is then an intermediate CA certificate for *cross certification*.

To verify the certificate you need to *verify the certificate chain*. So the `CA2` certificate is trusted, which verifies `CA2 << CA1 >>`, which finally verifies `CA1 << Alice >>`. This is performed by retrieving the public key within the *parent certificate* of the issuer and then use that to verify the signature of the *child certificate* of the subject. Besides verifying the signature over the "To Be Signed" part of the certificate you may also need to validate properties such as  validity period, key usage and so on.

Generally if there are two separate CA's that need to trust each other then the trust is established by issuing cross certificates: special intermediate certificates that establish the trust. These certificates may have additional properties that establish the type and level of trust. [Here](https://redmondmag.com/Articles/2003/11/01/Cross-Certification-Trusts.aspx?Page=1) is an explanation of the trust relationships, unfortunately without the intermediate certificates being shown.

The cross certification certificate is placed next to the original certificate in the trust chain. So while you have `C1`, `C1 << Alice >>` as the original chain you would have another chain `C2`, `C2 << C1 >>` (replacing `C1`) and finally `C1 << Alice >>`.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify has a very nice (IMO) picture of chaining (for X.509 certs used in SSL/TLS,. but the concept can be generalized)

Comment: That are good pictures. I'll try and forget that it mentions [decrypting the signature](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15997/1172) though. If somebody finds a resource that shows the certificate chains for cross certification I would be very grateful if you would post a link in this comment section!