# Should I encrypt the signature along with the message?

Tags: encryption, public-key, signature, symmetric

Given that A wants to send a message M to B,

I have 2 scenarios as shown:

[image]

The difference between the 2 is that for case 1, the digital signature is appended to the message before being encrypted using the symmetric key. For case 2, the digital signature is not encrypted using the symmetric key.

May I know which case is better? What are the security concerns of each of the case?

Comment: Im rather new to this topic and the explanation was a little too complex for me. I do not understand the example of the attack on how Eve can strip off the signature and add Eve's own signature. What is the point of that since Eve would not know the message? Does this mean that Case 1 is better?

Comment: There are 5 answers, there. Did you read all of them?

Comment: yes, but i still do not understand what is the weakness of case 2

Comment: The example on D.W,'s answer should be clear if you draw some figures. It can cause impersonization.

Comment: Beware that encryption of a hash is a terrible way to indicate signature generation. You can see my thoughts on it [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15997/1172).